# Why does my function run multiple times after UpdatePanel is loaded

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, updatepanel, pagerequestmanager

So I want to run some javaScript function after my updatepanel is updated, so I have:

```
function pageLoad() { 

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(panelLoaded);
}


function panelLoaded(sender, args) {
        alert("foobar");
}
```

With the above code, if I update the panel one time, "foobar" will be alerted one time; If I update the panel the second time, "foobar" will pop up twice; the third time I trigger the panel to update, "foobar" popped up three times... 4th time pop 4 times so on and so forth....

What caused this??

Thanks~~~

Comment: Looks like you're adding it over and over again in lprm.add_pageLoaded(panelLoaded)l. It probably never gets removed from prm and each time you're laoding the page it's adding a new instance. Try setting a breakpoint there and seeing how many panelLoaded calls are in prm. Does prm have a remove_pageLoaded(); option?

Comment: Thanks, you are right on the spot, it is Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_pageLoaded(panelLoaded);

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, problem seem to be having too many prm instances as Sam mentioned. I added Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_pageLoaded(panelLoaded);       after the alert() and everything is good.

Answer (score 4):

This is because pageLoad is executed during updatepanel postbacks as well. There is an easy solution:

```
function pageLoad(sender, eventArgs) {
    // If this is being executed by ajax
    if (eventArgs) {
        // And this is only a partial load
        if (eventArgs.get_isPartialLoad()) {
            // Don't perform any further processing
            return;
        }
    }
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(panelLoaded);
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too. I was adding a textchanged event, and it was behaving like first two requests were cancelled and third one actually processed. Due to which my progress indicator/loader was not work as it should have been

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening. `pageLoad` basically functions as a combination of [Application.Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397532.aspx) and [PageRequestManager.EndRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx). That means it works on Application Initialization ( approximately DOM Ready ) and on each `Partial PostBack`

So pageLoad works on all PostBacks; full and partial.

Now you are binding up pageLoaded event again on the ScriptManager's instance on every partial postback again and again causing this behaviour.